# I'm using alfresco 4.2.c and i'm wondering about LDAP-AD configuration

Tags: ldap, alfresco

I'm using alfresco 4.2.c and i'm wondering about LDAP-AD configuration ,

Is it possible to copy the configuration file "ldap-ad-authentication.properties" in the global properties file "alfresco-global.properties" without additional parameters ?

Comment: Alfresco has its own properties for LDAP-AD configurations, I would recommend you to look for alfresco specific properties of ldap-ad.

Comment: My alfresco LDAP-AD is Woking fine In 4.2c but in the new version 5.2 #alfresco-global.properties# file is messing .

Comment: It is not necessary to copy all properties. Only configure those you want to change in `alfresco-global.properties`.

Comment: Yes,  but still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This LDAP-AD conf work perfectly with alfresco community 5.2.0

**alfresco-global.properties**:

```
# LDAP
authentication.chain=alfrescoNtlm1:alfrescoNtlm,myldap:ldap-ad
synchronization.sinchronyzeChangesOnly=false
synchronization.syncWhenMissingPeopleLogIn=true
synchronization.syncOnStartup=true
synchronization.import.cron=0 0 18 * * ?


dir.root=C:/alfresco/alf_data2
db.username=alfresco2
db.password=alfresco2
db.name=alfresco2
db.host=localhost
db.port=5432 
db.pool.max=40
db.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/alfresco2
ftp.enabled=true
ftp.port=1121 
ftp.ipv6.enabled=false

# This flag enables use of this LDAP subsystem for authentication. It may be
# that this subsytem should only be used for synchronization, in which case
# this flag should be set to false.
ldap.authentication.active=true
#
# This properties file brings together the common options for LDAP authentication rather than editing the bean definitions
#
ldap.authentication.allowGuestLogin=false
# How to map the user id entered by the user to taht passed through to LDAP
# In Active Directory, this can either be the user principal name (UPN) or DN.
# UPNs are in the form <sAMAccountName>@domain and are held in the userPrincipalName attribute of a user
ldap.authentication.userNameFormat=%s@tidji.com
# The LDAP context factory to use
ldap.authentication.java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory
# The URL to connect to the LDAP server 
ldap.authentication.java.naming.provider.url=ldap://192.168.2.99:389
# The authentication mechanism to use for password validation
ldap.authentication.java.naming.security.authentication=simple
# Escape commas entered by the user at bind time
# Useful when using simple authentication and the CN is part of the DN and contains commas
ldap.authentication.escapeCommasInBind=false
# Escape commas entered by the user when setting the authenticated user
# Useful when using simple authentication and the CN is part of the DN and contains commas, and the escaped \, is 
# pulled in as part of an LDAP sync
# If this option is set to true it will break the default home folder provider as space names can not contain \
ldap.authentication.escapeCommasInUid=false
# Comma separated list of user names who should be considered administrators by default
ldap.authentication.defaultAdministratorUserNames=alfresco
# This flag enables use of this LDAP subsystem for user and group
# synchronization. It may be that this subsytem should only be used for 
# authentication, in which case this flag should be set to false.
ldap.synchronization.active=true
# The authentication mechanism to use for synchronization    * :) *
ldap.synchronization.java.naming.security.authentication=simple
# The default principal to bind with (only used for LDAP sync). This should be a UPN or DN  * :( *
ldap.synchronization.java.naming.security.principal=alfresco@tidji.com
# The password for the default principal (only used for LDAP sync)  * :)  *
ldap.synchronization.java.naming.security.credentials=*******
# If positive, this property indicates that RFC 2696 paged results should be
# used to split query results into batches of the specified size. This
# overcomes any size limits imposed by the LDAP server.  *  :(  *
ldap.synchronization.queryBatchSize=1000
# If positive, this property indicates that range retrieval should be used to fetch
# multi-valued attributes (such as member) in batches of the specified size.
# Overcomes any size limits imposed by Active Directory.      *   :(    *   
ldap.synchronization.attributeBatchSize=1000
# The query to select all objects that represent the groups to import.
ldap.synchronization.groupQuery=(objectclass\=group)
# The query to select objects that represent the groups to import that have changed since a certain time.
ldap.synchronization.groupDifferentialQuery=(&(objectclass\=group)(!(whenChanged<\={0})))
# The query to select all objects that represent the users to import.
ldap.synchronization.personQuery=(&(objectclass\=user)(userAccountControl\:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803\:\=512))
# The query to select objects that represent the users to import that have changed since a certain time.
ldap.synchronization.personDifferentialQuery=(&(objectclass\=user)(userAccountControl\:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803\:\=512)(!(whenChanged<\={0})))
# The group search base restricts the LDAP group query to a sub section of tree on the LDAP server.
ldap.synchronization.groupSearchBase=ou\=User,dc\=tidji,dc\=com
# The user search base restricts the LDAP user query to a sub section of tree on the LDAP server.
ldap.synchronization.userSearchBase=ou\=User,dc\=tidji,dc\=com
# The name of the operational attribute recording the last update time for a group or user.
ldap.synchronization.modifyTimestampAttributeName=whenChanged
# The timestamp format. Unfortunately, this varies between directory servers. *  :(   *
ldap.synchronization.timestampFormat=yyyyMMddHHmmss'.0Z'
# The attribute name on people objects found in LDAP to use as the uid in Alfresco
ldap.synchronization.userIdAttributeName=sAMAccountName
# The attribute on person objects in LDAP to map to the first name property in Alfresco
ldap.synchronization.userFirstNameAttributeName=givenName
# The attribute on person objects in LDAP to map to the last name property in Alfresco
ldap.synchronization.userLastNameAttributeName=sn
# The attribute on person objects in LDAP to map to the email property in Alfresco
ldap.synchronization.userEmailAttributeName=mail
# The attribute on person objects in LDAP to map to the organizational id  property in Alfresco
ldap.synchronization.userOrganizationalIdAttributeName=company
# The default home folder provider to use for people created via LDAP import
ldap.synchronization.defaultHomeFolderProvider=userHomesHomeFolderProvider
# The attribute on LDAP group objects to map to the authority name property in Alfresco
ldap.synchronization.groupIdAttributeName=cn
# The attribute on LDAP group objects to map to the authority display name property in Alfresco
ldap.synchronization.groupDisplayNameAttributeName=displayName
# The group type in LDAP
#ldap.synchronization.groupType=group
# The person type in LDAP
#ldap.synchronization.personType=user
# The attribute in LDAP on group objects that defines the DN for its members
ldap.synchronization.groupMemberAttributeName=member
# If true progress estimation is enabled. When enabled, the user query has to be run twice in order to count entries.
ldap.synchronization.enableProgressEstimation=true
# Requests timeout, in miliseconds, use 0 for none (default)
ldap.authentication.java.naming.read.timeout=0
```